# Inheritance in C Sharp

Tags: c#, inheritance

[image]

i am new to C#, can u please explain whats wrong with this statement  `bigderive c = new bigbase();`

Comment: a bigbase is not a bigderive. (assuming your names make sense). YOu cannot say that a bigbase is a bigderive, it isnt

Comment: inheritance works the other way round `bigbase c = new begderive();`.

Comment: Don't put a image of the code next time.copy and paste your code here :)

Answer (score 1):

See it like this: a sports-car is a car with some extras. If you store the sports-car in a car spot, all we know is: it's a car. But it is 100% a car.

If you however try to store a car in a sport-car spot, we can't be certain that it actually is a sports-car. That is why that statement is wrong.

If you would say `bigbase c = new bigderivce()` that would work, because `bigderive` is 100% certain to be at least `bigbase` + some extras.

an example:

```
class Car {
  public void drive() { 
    // do stuff
  }
}
class SportsCar : Car {
  public void driveFaster() {

  }
}

Car car1 = new SportsCar();
car1.driveFast(); // this won't compile, because a Car has no driveFast() method by definition

SportsCar car2 = new SportsCar();
car2.driveFast(); // this works

SportsCar car3 = new Car(); // let's assume this compile
car3.driveFast(); // which method of Car would be called now? car3 is a Car, which has no driveFast() method by declaration.
```